# How do I browserify a JS file with global variables?

Tags: javascript, browserify, browserify-shim

On [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) 's page they explicitly try to help with the use case I have:

> Modules that just declare a var foo = ... on the script level and assume it gets attached to the window object. Since the only way they will ever be run is in the global context — "ahem, … NO?!"

I have a problem getting this to work. I have a test project with browserify and browserify and I am trying to use the following file as a browserify module:

***Note that we use two inter-depending functions and jquery in the ugly.js file!***

**ugly.js:**

```
var x = function() {
  alert("im a global variable using jquery version:" +$.fn.jquery);
};

var y = function() {
  x();
};
```

I want to use it in **main.js:**

```
var ugly = require("./ugly.js");
ugly.y();
```

I tried to add the following in my package.json but to no avail, the "ugly" module is not found....

**package.json:**

```
...snip...
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "./ugly.js": "ugly"
  }
```

Comment: Is it required to specify the file extension? Try w/o `.js`.

Comment: No, but removing it still doesn't help.